# Anaconda cannot start Qt Console ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, anaconda

Trying to run Qt Console from anaconda results in  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

[image]

The only thing I've managed to find is to do pip install -- pywin32==227 which has not worked for me.

Also, I cannot get Spyder to launch I see it initially loading but then it just disappears and I don't get any message.

Comment: Did you install everything or did you copy it from somewhere?  This error USUALLY means you are loading a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process.  Which Python did you install?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm fairly certain I installed everything although I do also have a 32bit version of python from microsoft store.
Currently the default python command is Python 3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Although I think I  have multiple versions 3.7,3,8, 3.9 installed with 3.9 I think being the conda version.

Comment: Uninstall python, all of them, 32 bit or 64 bit. Download and install this:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/python-3.9.6-amd64.exe

Comment: @MujeebIshaque  I uninstalled all versions of python except the one with anaconda which I cannot uninstall without uninstalling anaconda this error still remains also windows does not recognize this new python and the python command now opens the Microsoft store